# SQL Server Count records from parent category and all subcategories

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Currently I have a stored procedure where I create a table and query the table to get my desired result, the result being an infinitely tiered child/parent table that allows me to display the data on my ASP Classic based webpage.

This procedure is:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Categories TABLE(
    CatID INT NOT NULL,
    CatName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    ParentID INT
)

INSERT INTO @Categories 
SELECT CatID, CatName, ParentID = NULL FROM Categories
WHERE CatName NOT IN (
    SELECT CatName FROM Categories c 
    INNER JOIN CategoriesRel r ON c.CatID = r.ChildID)
UNION
SELECT CatID, CatName, cr.ParentID FROM Categories 
INNER JOIN CategoriesRel cr ON cr.ChildID = Categories.CatID
ORDER BY CatID;

WITH r AS (
    SELECT CatID, CatName, ParentID, depth=0 ,Sort=CAST(CatName As VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM @Categories WHERE ParentID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.CatID, c.CatName, c.ParentID, Depth=r.Depth+1 ,Sort=r.Sort+CAST(c.CatName AS VARCHAR(200))
    FROM r INNER JOIN @Categories c ON r.CatID=c.ParentID WHERE r.Depth<32767
)

SELECT CatID, CatName=replicate('-',r.Depth*3)+r.CatName,
(SELECT COUNT(BsnID) FROM Businesses WHERE Businesses.CatID = r.CatID) AS CatCount
FROM r ORDER BY Sort OPTION(maxrecursion 32767);
```

The problem with this is the count query at the bottom.

```
(SELECT COUNT(BsnID) FROM Businesses WHERE Businesses.CatID = r.CatID) AS CatCount
```

If I use this specific piece of code, I only get the count of rows returned for a specific Category ID. For example this is the current result:

```
CatID | CatName              | CatCount
______|______________________|_________
1016  | Antiques             | 1
1021  | Automotive           | 1
1024  | ---Repair            | 1
1026  | ------Engine Repair  | 1
1035  | ---Tyres             | 1
1002  | Building             | 0
```

I need the result to be something like this:

```
CatID | CatName              | CatCount
______|______________________|_________
1016  | Antiques             | 1
1021  | Automotive           | 4
1024  | ---Repair            | 2
1026  | ------Engine Repair  | 1
1035  | ---Tyres             | 1
1002  | Building             | 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

EDIT: Included is some SQL for testing purposes

```
CREATE TABLE Categories(CatID int NOT NULL,CatName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (CatID));

CREATE TABLE CategoriesRel(CatLinkID int NOT NULL,ParentID int NOT NULL,ChildID int NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (CatLinkID),FOREIGN KEY (ParentID) REFERENCES Categories(CatID),FOREIGN KEY (ChildID) REFERENCES Categories(CatID);

CREATE TABLE Businesses(BsnID int NOT NULL,BsnName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,CatID int NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (BsnID),FOREIGN KEY (CatID) REFERENCES Categories(CatID);

INSERT INTO Categories VALUES ('1','Antique'),('2','Automotive'),('3','Building'),('4','Tyres'),('5','Repair'),('6','Engine Repairs');
INSERT INTO CategoriesRel VALUES ('1', '2','4'),('1','2','5'),('1','5','6');
INSERT INTO Businesses VALUES ('1','Test1','2'),('2','Test2','4'),('3','Test3','5'),('4','Test4','6');
```

Comment: can you make a T-SQL procedure ? what's your use case ?

Comment: The use case is relatively simple, user interacts with a webpage to display all categories. Said webpage executes the procedure to display a full list of Categories in the db... As for the T-SQL, I would but I'm in no means an expert with SQL, I wouldn't know the best way to achieve my required results!

Comment: `Antiques             | 1` and `Building             | 0` => typos ?

Comment: They are categories with no child categories, so they have 1 or 0 businesses in those categories respectively

Comment: can you give us the create table + a few line for testing purpose ?

Comment: @Blag Added some code at the bottom of my post

Comment: I may suggest you a really good lecture as you work with tree structure : [Managing Hierarchical Data](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), it's for mysql, but you can use it with SQL-server. It's a really good way to deal with Tree when most of the work is read (write is slow)

Comment: I will take a look, thankyou for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the `WHERE ParentID IS NULL` part of the CTE, and add a `RootId` field.  This will let you find the count of the children for each level of parent.

```
;WITH r AS (
    SELECT CatID, CatName, ParentID, CatID RootId, depth=0 ,Sort=CAST(CatName As VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM @Categories 
    --WHERE ParentID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.CatID, c.CatName, c.ParentID, RootId, Depth=r.Depth+1 ,Sort=r.Sort+CAST(c.CatName AS VARCHAR(200))
    FROM r 
    INNER JOIN @Categories c ON r.CatID=c.ParentID 
    WHERE r.Depth<32767
)
```

This gives you a row for each level of the hierarchy.  Parent categories appear multiple times, but with different RootIds.  This will let us get a count at each level of the hierarcy:

```
+-------+---------------+----------+--------+-------+-------------------------------+
| CatID |    CatName    | ParentID | RootId | depth |             Sort              |
+-------+---------------+----------+--------+-------+-------------------------------+
|  1002 | Building      | NULL     |   1002 |     0 | Building                      |
|  1016 | Antiques      | NULL     |   1016 |     0 | Antiques                      |
|  1021 | Automotive    | NULL     |   1021 |     0 | Automotive                    |
|  1024 | Repair        | 1021     |   1024 |     0 | Repair                        |
|  1026 | Engine Repair | 1024     |   1026 |     0 | Engine Repair                 |
|  1035 | Tyres         | 1021     |   1035 |     0 | Tyres                         |
|  1026 | Engine Repair | 1024     |   1024 |     1 | RepairEngine Repair           |
|  1024 | Repair        | 1021     |   1021 |     1 | AutomotiveRepair              |
|  1035 | Tyres         | 1021     |   1021 |     1 | AutomotiveTyres               |
|  1026 | Engine Repair | 1024     |   1021 |     2 | AutomotiveRepairEngine Repair |
+-------+---------------+----------+--------+-------+-------------------------------+
```

If you group by RootId and get the `COUNT()`, it gives you the numbers you're looking for:

```
select RootId, count(b.CatId) catCount
from r 
left outer join Businesses b on r.CatID = b.CatId
group by rootid

+--------+----------+
| RootId | CatCount |
+--------+----------+
|   1002 |        0 |
|   1016 |        1 |
|   1021 |        4 |
|   1024 |        2 |
|   1026 |        1 |
|   1035 |        1 |
+--------+----------+
```

The rest of the query is just getting the Sort and indented CatName.  You want to get the deepest child for each category:

```
select r.CatId, CatName, max(depth) MaxDepth
from r
group by r.catId, CatName
```

The final query is:

```
SELECT y.CatID,
replicate('-',y.MaxDepth*3)+y.CatName CatName,
x.CatCount
FROM (select RootId, count(b.CatId) catCount
      from r 
      left outer join Businesses b on r.CatID = b.CatId
      group by rootid) x
join (select r.CatId, CatName, max(depth) MaxDepth
      from r
      group by r.catId, CatName) y on y.CatID = x.RootId
order by (select Sort from r where r.CatID = x.RootId and r.depth = y.MaxDepth)
OPTION(maxrecursion 32767);
```

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly, can you explain a little bit in depth about how it works? Thankyou

Comment: Nice work, I was trying a `with` solution too, but without any success; +1

Comment: @RhysRuffell I've added some detail to the answer.

Comment: @Blag Thanks.  I answered a similar question the other day, which helped with this one.  This one was trickier, though.