# Hi there, i need a help, i want to display total post count in parents category , how do i that?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, jinja2

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['category_list']=Category.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True).annotate(num=Count('products'))

    return context
```

### index.html

```
   {% for category in category_list %}
    <div class="single-category">
        <a href="{{category.get_absolute_url}}">
            {{category.title}} 
            {{category.num}}
            <span style="color: gray;"> 
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor%}
```

## #

i got data like this 
Electronic 0
Jobs 0
but in child category i have two post,
i wanna display in parent category total post count in all subcategories

Comment: post your models also

Comment: category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 verbose_name='Category',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name='products',
                                 blank=True,
                                 null=True,
                                 )

Comment: привет Дастан Алымбеков! With the data you provide I'm not sure about how to help you, but if you can alter the models, I think this could help (even the question is for another language, the idea looks quite similar) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803863/sql-server-count-records-from-parent-category-and-all-subcategories
добро пожаловать, кстати :-)